# duplicate div containing set of fields in the same dom

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, dom, handlebars.js

i am loading handlebar templates in the two div locations(like add and edit tabs both are jsps)  from the same page. so i have duplicate elements in the DOM object, since it is a template which is coming from server location. you can see the sample code below

```
<div id="add">
    <div id="exploding">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="edit">
    <div id="exploding">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't modify the div container ids i.e exploding since some javascript functions attached to it based on that id to explode address field.
here the problem is if i made any changes to the edit tab, address "exploding" div, it is effecting in add tab address "exploding" since ids are repeated. i have tried jquery detach method to remove the dom elements, but didn't get proper result. Its a web application based on spring boot.
is there any possibility to load jsps dynamically through jquery, i have tried load method as well, but the call is going through controller. I didn't feel it as better option.
Thanks & Regards
krishna K

Comment: ids should be unique

Comment: Hi Pete , This   
 <div id="add">{addMarhup}</div>
 <div id="add">{editMarkup}</div>

Comment: I understand, but html and js work on the premise that ids are unique and having multiple of the same will lead to issues with code not working properly - if you have multiple of the same id, then consider using a class instead - eg getElementById - only gets the first element with a matching id, getElement**s**ByClassName - gets elements (plural)

Comment: yes i can, but here the problem is the ids are associated with some address exploding functionality, which is from third party source. since both divs having same class actually, if i click on address field in edit tab, the explode is happening in add tab.

Comment: and that's exactly what I have explained in my previous comment

Comment: if i change the class name, the exploding functionality won't happen, because it is dependent on class name that should be strictly 'exploding'. in the sample code i have mentioned wrongly like 'id', actually it is class only

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] demonstrating your error as you don't even include any of the code that is not working, so how do you expect us to debug it?

Comment: i am very sorry that ,i can't share the code since it is a violation of T&Cs